# How to align this menu to center (Spanish only)

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://reliancetrustgroup.com/es/

I want to align this menu to center ... for English menu looks good

```
#site-navigation
{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

We studied the code and found this code sequence.

What should I change so that it looks better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, etc.) in the question.  We want questions to be helpful to future visitors and as soon as you fix your site, no one will be able to see and reproduce the problem, making it worthless to future visitors.  Your question will be in danger of being closed until that is taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class site-navigation remove the width and it should word just fine! 
This is happening because you stablished the menu size as 980px and it's bigger than that. You can also change the px size of site-navigation to 1200px or something like that, and it will work too!